# How check exist element in postgresql jsonb column with jpa criteria?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, jsonb, jpa-criteria

I have an entity as follow:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@TypeDef(name = "JsonbType", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String content;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @Type(type = "JsonbType")
    private readTimes UserTimeSet;
}

public class UserTimeSet extend HashSet<UserTime> {
}

public class UserTime implement Serializable {
     private String username;
     private Date time;
}
```

Some records are as follow:

```
 id |                 read_times                 
----+--------------------------------------
  1 | [{"username": "user1", "time": 12312412}, {"username": "user2", "time": 123}]
  2 | [{"username": "user2", "time": 713}]
  3 | []
  4 | []
```

For saving object to column with Hibernate, I use [Hibernate Types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) project.Now I want to get records there is no `user1` in `read_times` with JPA criteria? the response must be records with id: `2`, `3`, `4`.

**Update**:
I solved with query but can't convert to JPA Criteria:

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE jsonb_path_exists("read_times", '$[*] ? (@.username == "user1")')
```

Answer (score 0):

If using [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_regexp.htm#regexp), REGEXP is supported, and will work on Postgres,

You can also use the SQL function to call any SQL specific syntax inside [JPQL](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_sql.htm#sql)

An example for Predicates are as follows:
Predicate inJsonNumbers = cb
.function("jsonb_extract_path_text",
String.class,
root.get("json"),
cb.literal("number"))
.in(filter.getJsonNumbers())

```
Predicate inJsonNames = cb
        .function("jsonb_extract_path_text", 
                String.class, 
                root.get("json"), 
                cb.literal("name"))
        .in(filter.getJsonNames())
```

ALso, you can write a custom `SQLFunction` for the `CAST(jsonField->'key' AS float)` expression and then use that in JPQL.

```
public String render(Type firstArgumentType, List args, SessionFactoryImplementor factory) throws QueryException {
    return "CAST(" + args.get(0).toString() + "->'" + args.get(1).toString() + "' AS float)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

with temp AS(
select t.id, jsonb_array_elements(t.read_times)->>'username' as username from table_Name t
)

select id from table_name where id not in
(
select id from temp
where
username='user1'
)

[image]

Comment: I want to query with Criteria